# l form to save data in Access

Tags: excel

Good day to all !!

I manage a contact center and require the staff to capture some data to calculate their productivity

This could've been done easily through ACCESS forms, but the team is not allowed to have ACCESS due to some policies

I wanted to know if i am to create a few predefined fields in excel for data entry (Dropdowns and some free text), where the agents enter the information each time, then click a "Submit" button.

Once the "Submit" button is clicked, the data is then passed into an ACCESS table, and the excel fields are reset to blank.

Note: Each agent has an excel file with their name stored on our shared drive. The ACCESS is also stored on the shared drive. Paths are predefined and fixed.

Can anyone please help with this

I'm sure this has been posted somewhere before, but I cant seem to find the exact requirements.

Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far I have defined the fields and created the display. I also created a button but have not coded it. I need this button "submit" to send the information in the defined fields into a table (Excel or Access) doesnt matter. Can you help :)?

Comment: Once again, please show us what have you done so far. We will help you, once you show you made some effort solving your problem.

Comment: hi Lowak, do i upload a file? how? Sorry but im new here

Comment: You can make your description more specific, add what you have done so far. If you want to upload a file you do this using any free filehost website and post a link.

Comment: I've worked on a template i found online and it suits the purpose. The only issue is that it copies everything into a worksheet within the same excel workbook. I am trying to copy this date into another workbook into another location "c:\reports\consolidated.xlsx". Can you please help with this last minor bit :) file in the below link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3wea245lmek8hef/FormSheet.xls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. Copy, paste and adjust workbook name.

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet

    Dim wb1 As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim myCell As Range

    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "D5,D7,D9,D11,D13"

    Set inputWks = Worksheets("Input")
    Set historyWks = Worksheets("PartsData")

    Set wb1 = Workbooks("1.xls").Worksheets("PartsData") 'change Workbook

    With inputWks
        Set myRng = .Range(myCopy)

        If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With

    With wb1
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            .Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With

    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With
End Sub
```

Edit:

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdateLogWorksheet()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim historyWks As Worksheet
    Dim inputWks As Worksheet
    Dim wb1 As Worksheet

    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim oCol As Long

    Dim wb_path As String
    Dim myCopy As String
    Dim wb_name As String

    Dim myRng As Range
    Dim myCell As Range

    'cells to copy from Input sheet - some contain formulas
    myCopy = "D5,D7,D9,D11,D13"
    wb_name = "1.xls" '2nd workbook name
    wb_path = "C:\Reports\" & wb_name '2nd workbook path on HDD

    Set inputWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Input") 'form sheet
    Set historyWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PartsData") 'data in form sheet

    Set myRng = inputWks.Range(myCopy)

    If Application.CountA(myRng) <> myRng.Cells.Count Then
        MsgBox "Please fill in all the cells!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'if 2nd workbook file does not exists, message will pop up
    If Dir(wb_path) = "" Then
        MsgBox ("File does not exists")
        Exit Sub:

    'if exists it will open and become invisible
    Else
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=wb_path
        Application.Windows(wb_name).Visible = False
        Set wb1 = Workbooks(wb_name).Worksheets("PartsData") 'data in 2nd workbook

        'copy data to 2nd workbook
        With wb1
            nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
            With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
                .Value = Now
                .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
            End With
            .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
            oCol = 3
            For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
                .Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
                oCol = oCol + 1
            Next myCell
        End With

        Application.Windows(wb_name).Visible = True
        Workbooks(wb_name).Close True

    End If

    'copy data to form sheet
    With historyWks
        nextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        With .Cells(nextRow, "A")
            .Value = Now
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
        End With
        .Cells(nextRow, "B").Value = Application.UserName
        oCol = 3
        For Each myCell In myRng.Cells
            .Cells(nextRow, oCol).Value = myCell.Value
            oCol = oCol + 1
        Next myCell
    End With


    'clear input cells that contain constants
    With inputWks
      On Error Resume Next
         With .Range(myCopy).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
              .ClearContents
              Application.GoTo .Cells(1) ', Scroll:=True
         End With
      On Error GoTo 0
    End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks lowak :) i am getting an error though in this line.  Set wb1 = Workbooks("1.xls").Worksheets("PartsData"). Even if this works, i want to set the destination of the new worksheet in a different folder, not in the same one as the current file.

Comment: Probably because u don't have workbooks with name 1.xls. As I wrote in anwser, you need to adjust this part to your workbook name.

Comment: FYI though, i did create a workbook named "1.xls" and created a worksheet with the name "PartsData". but didn't work. This workbook is in the same folder as the sheet

Comment: Are you 100% sure you copied it right? I created also two workbooks to check if it works and it does for me.

Comment: I simply erased the entire macro and pasted the one u gave me above. Let me try again and see what happens

Comment: Oh... one more thing. It will work only if workbook is opened. If you want to save data when workbook("1.xls") is closed I need to change the code.

Comment: Oh haha stupid of me, It did work when its opened. I do need it to work when it is closed though, is that possible? I will have over 20 people work on this form, each on their own sheet simultaneously over 24 hour period and will not be able to keep the sheet opened all the time. One last thing, I also need to have this sheet in a different folder, possible? I tried this code but didnt work: Set historyWks = "C:\reports" & strName & ".xlsx"

Comment: Would it also be possible for the sheet to paste the data into both "Current worksheet" and "1.xls" for example?

Comment: It looks like this: you cannot save data to closed workbook. The only solution in this case is open workbook for a short period of time and after save, close it. As you said work will involve many people, so it is probably bad solution. You can create database in access and then it is possible to save it to access. It is possible to paste same data to 2 sheets.

Comment: You've helped a lot so far, thank you so much for this. I can create a DB in access with same fields but have no idea how to pass data into it. I know it's too much but it would be a huge help. In the meantime i can keep the 1.xlsx opened but this file is available in a different folder "i.e c\reports\1.xlsx" how can i do this? Finally, i want the data to be copied into both the current file and  1.xlsx. Im so sorry for all these requests but you are literally saving me 30 working hours per week :)

Comment: For access solution read this thread: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?22628-Solved-Add-data-to-a-closed-workbook I will help you with this code, but you need to wait a little, I have some other work to do now.

Comment: Take forever :) you're awesome just for taking the time to help me in the first place !!

Comment: Actually i did some changes, ill share the final code with you shortly, let me know what you think !!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks :) let me see how I can modify to save in access, should not be major change I guess since the data is being sent we just modify the destination.

Comment: Well it is a little different but I think you can make it work. I pasted you link above.